# Proof of diffraction equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffraction

If light incident on a grating makes an angle φ with respect to the normal to the grating, show that dsin(θ)=mλ becomes d[sin(θ-φ)+sin(φ)]=mλ.

I began by showing:

```
d[sin(θ-φ)+sin(φ)]=mλ, θi=φ=θ at m=0
```

(see my note after about why I think this line is wrong)
then:

```
d(sin(θ-θ) + sin(θ))=mλ
d(sin(0)+sin(θ))=mλ
d(0+sin(θ))=mλ
dsin(θ)=mλ
```

It decomposes nicely to what I'm asked for but now that I look at it again I see that I've also declared m=0 which means that:

```
dsin(θ)=0λ
dsin(θ)=0
```

which implies that either d=0 or sin=0, both of which I don't find probable.
I suppose I'm stuck on where or how to introduce φ to the equation. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting boggled down with the math and forgetting the physics. I suggest you look at the geometry of the situation. To derive $d \sin\theta = m \lambda$ you would have shown that the difference in path length for rays hitting two adjacent grooves is $d\sin\theta_d$, where $\theta_d$ is the angle between the diffracted beam and the normal. This is when the incident light is head-on ($\theta_i = 0$).

When the rays hit the grating at an angle $\theta_i$, there is an extra contribution to the difference in path lengths. Can you calculate this extra contribution?

Also, I'm not sure if your initial equation is correct. Is $\theta$ measured relative to the incident beam, rather than the normal? In that case, what you have written is correct, i.e,. $\theta_d = \theta-\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!

What I am understanding here is:

Obviously the angle of the incident ray has an effect on the angle at which I would find the diffracted wavelength. It seems like as φ gets larger, θ gets smaller. The math seems to suggest that if I were to shine the light almost directly horizontally to the grating, I would find θ almost at the normal.

I don't understand how EXACTLY these two are related. It would make sense that as sin(θ−φ) gets smaller, a larger contribution is made by sin(φ). However, I have never seen this equation before and am confused as to 2nd sin.

Comment: Do you understand why there are two $sin$s?